# Javascript - Can't break from loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, while-loop

I can't find a way to break from this loop.
 Everything I tried so far failed.

```
var st = 20;
var timeNow = new Date();  

var isprinted = false; 

var time = st - timeNow.getHours();
while (isprinted === false) {
    while(time = 2) {
        console.log("2h screenLeft"); 
        isprinted = true;
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: change `time = 2` (assignment) to `time === 2` (comparison)? Still, this loop condition doesn't make sense to me. Did you mean `if (time === 2) { ... }`? The outer while loop is equally confusing. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: "doesnt work" is not a useful problem description. Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single equal sign in the condition of your inner loop:

```
(time = 2)
```

That assignment will always return `true`, so your inner `while` never ends.

In JavaScript, a single equal sign is for assignment, not comparison.  Change that to two (comparison with conversion) or three (comparison without conversion) equal signs.

```
(time === 2)
```

You need to be VERY careful with `while` loops because it is very easy to run into situations where the loop termination condition never occurs. Even after fixing the equal sign issue, your `time` variable doesn't seem to ever change, so you will always enter the inner loop.

Now, let's look at the rest of your code, and follow it along:

```
var st = 20;
var timeNow = new Date();  
var isprinted = false; 
var time = st - timeNow.getHours();
```

Right here, you are checking `isprinted` to see if it is exactly `false`.

```
while (isprinted === false) {
```

This is Ok, but is simpler to just write:

```
while (!isprinted) {
```

So, since you set the variable to `false`, we enter the first loop and hit the condition for the second (and let's assume you've fixed the equal sign issue):

```
    while(time === 2) {
        console.log("2h screenLeft"); 
        isprinted = true;
        return 0;
    }
```

To exit the loop, use `break` not `return`.

However, since there isn't any other dedicated code for the outer loop other than the inner loop, you should just have one loop that is based on a compound condition and you won't need to worry about breaking out of it at all:

The final code:

```
var st = 20;
var timeNow = new Date();  
var isprinted = false; 
var time = st - timeNow.getHours();

while (!isprinted  && time === 2) {
        console.log("2h screenLeft"); 
        isprinted = true;
}
```

Here's a test case:

```js
    var st = 20;
    var timeNow = new Date();  
    var isprinted = false; 
    var time = st - timeNow.getHours();
    
    time = 2; // Forced value for testing

    while (!isprinted  && time === 2) {
            console.log("2h screenLeft"); 
            isprinted = true;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that solves the issue. If `time === 2` is true and enters the while loop, `time` will never be anything other than 2, so it will still loop infinitely. Also, using `return` outside of a function is a syntax error. What they really need is `(time === 2)` in conjunction with swapping the `return` keyword with `break`.

Comment: @mhodges The outer while loop loops infinitely when `time != 2` as `isPrinted` never changes. Something else is amiss.

Comment: @le_m Yes, that's also true.

Comment: Not sure about final code. Can be done with `if` statement if that's what the OP really wants to do. I think they want to keep checking `st - timeNow.getHours()` until `time === 2` (without locking up the browser i'm assuming). Should maybe be a `setInterval`? Hard to know until we can get feedback from the OP

Comment: @mhodges I never use `while` loops because they are bug magnets, but that's what the OP is using, so that's what I'm posting. This code will continue until `time` becomes `2` (which will happen once a day) at which point `isprinted` will become `true` (which will cause the loop to end).

Comment: @mhodges You can see from my test case that if `time` becomes `2` the loop will stop.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Understandable. My point was just that (given the current code) `time` does not continue to get evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break from your loop, because you are setting your time to 2 instead of checking for its value.

Try this instead:

```
  while (isprinted === false) {
   while(time == 2) {
    console.log("2h screenLeft"); 
    isprinted = true;
    break;  //This should be break, so you can obviously break from the loop
      } 
    if(time != 2)
       break;
   }
```

Comment: Cannot return from a non-function - throws a syntax error. Need to use `break` instead.

Comment: Yes I know. I just forgot to change that in my answer! Would really appreciate it if you removed the -1 :) Cheers

Comment: Still loops infinitely if `time != 2`. Will remove downvote when that is corrected.

Comment: Still needs work. Unless `time == 2`, the `isprinted` flag never gets set to anything other than false. No need for `if(isprinted == true)`, the outer while loop will take care of that

Comment: Fixed it. Again, my hastiness gets the best of me.